# Verifying Stokes' theorem with a disc

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

$ \iint_S \nabla \times \mathbf F \cdot dS = \int_{\partial S} \mathbf F \cdot dr $

Where S is the disc $ x^2 + y^2 \le 1$ in the plane $z = 0 $

The vector Field is $ \mathbf F = x^2i + (2xy+x)j + zk $

I've worked out that $ \nabla \times \mathbf F = (2y+1)k $

Where do I go on from here?

Comment: Parameterize $S$ and $\partial S$ and evaluate the integrals.

Comment: how do i parameterize $\partial S $ ?

Comment: Since $S = \{x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$, $\partial S = \{x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$, but this is the unit circle in the $xy$-plane.